# Date value in SharePoint is one day off while retrieving

Tags: development, csom, date-time

I am saving a DateTime value in one of the field in SharePoint list :

```
//request is an entity that has all he fields in the list, I am only showing DueDate in the below code
    if (txtdatepicker.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        DateTime dueDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(txtdatepicker.Text, out dueDate))
        {
             request.DueDate = dueDate;//Output {9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM}
        }
    }
```

The Date is correctly saved in SharePoint list as **Due Date**: `9/30/2017`.

Now the issue is when i try to retrieve this Date value :

```
if (LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate] != null)
  req.DueDate = (DateTime)LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate];//Output {9/29/2017 6:30:00 PM}
```

The output i get here is totally different from that of the value that is saved. How to fetch the correct Date value from a SharPoint DateTime column?

Comment: SharePoint saves the dates in UTC string format. While you are retrieving date, you need to convert it as per the the server time zone format. you can get the server timezone from regional setting in site setting.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. If I do this `DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate])).ToLocalTime()` it works fine but is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: it is okay if all the users are in same time zone. if you have multiple server with different time zone than it may cause an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working on the server. Any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SPTimeZone.UTCToLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sptimezone.utctolocaltime.aspx) method to convert the UTC date time to local date time.

Comment: I tried this `ClientResult<DateTime> dt= oTimeZone.UTCToLocalTime((DateTime)LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate]);` and i get the output as `MinDate` i.e `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`

Comment: Use this DateTime dt=oTimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(DateTime.Parse(LI[Constants.FieldName_Re‌​qLst_DueDate].ToString()));

Comment: i know this is bit old thread, but need to check if some one has done this thing while using rest API. I am having same issue and trying to manipulate using java script. Thanks.